# How do I copy contacts from my SIM card to a Moto G8 Power?

Tags: contacts, sim-card

Well there's not really more to say about my question apart from: Yes, I've looked for this feature on the Internet and on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy all contacts from your SIM card using the **Contacts ap**p.

Open it, select the **burger menu** in the top left corner, open **Settings** -> **Import** ->  **SIM card**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realize the difference between the Contacts app in the Menu and the Contacts on the start screen!